# Sending a newsletter with a new connection for each 20 mails in the queue in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-9

I have a web app that basically sends a newsletter to a large set of users on a user specific date.
Recently my web provider limited the number of emails per session to 20, so when I try to send the mails I get the error `Expected response code "250" but got code "451", with message "451-Requested action aborted 451 Mails per session limit exceeded.".`
counting the number of emails in my queue showed me the error appears once the 21 email is added to the queue.

I'm trying to workaround this by making smaller queues, each containing only 20 emails, processing the queue and then opening a new connection for the next 20 mails.
I don't mind if the next batch is sent a bit later.
However, I'm not exactly sure how to implement this in laravel. Any Suggestions?

my app\console\command looks (shortend) like this

```
class SendReminderEmails extends Command
{
      protected $signature = 'email:reminder';
      public function handle()
         {
           $pending_users = TargetUser->get(); 
           foreach($pending_users as $user){  
               $maildate = $user->reminder_date;   
               if (date('Y-m-d') == $maildate){
                   $user_info = User::where('id',$user->user_id)->first();
                   $email = $user_info->email;
                   Mail::to($email)->queue(new SendReminder($user_info));
               }
          }
}
```

(With SendReminder being a Class that extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue)

thanks!

Comment: What is “session”? This code will send mails separetly - one letter - one connection.

Comment: Hmm I don't really know. That error message is all I've got to work with. I was just assuming the whole queue gets processed in one connection

Comment: Nope, one mail = one connection. Speak with your provider for details of this error. BTW check your queue driver. If it “sync” - change to redis or something async.

Comment: thanks, changing my queue driver to an async one (database) did the trick!